# Not able to set table height

Tags: html, css

I have a simple html table
I am not able to set the height for this table

Am i missing something

```
    <table border="1"  id="abc1"  height="10px;" >
     <tr><td><b>Name</b></td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>Name</b></td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>Name</b></td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>Name</b></td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You are setting the height but your content overflows, so it automatically readjusts the height to fit your content

Comment: set table display as block using css (display:block)

Answer (score 20):

Place table inside a div and give height to that div.

Comment: refer link: http://maxdesign.com.au/jobs/sample-fixed-thead/index.htm
Here table header is kept fixed and rest of the table is scroll-able.
This is done by giving certain height to <tbody> and giving it property of "overflow: auto;"

Comment: Didn't work for me. Descendent containers within the table can render this solution ineffective.

Answer (score 11):

Both border and height, which you're trying to set, are actually CSS attributes, not HTML.
Set them in the following way:

```
<table id="abc1" style="border: 1px; height:10px;" >
     <tr><td><b>Name</b></td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>Name</b></td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>Name</b></td></tr>
     <tr><td><b>Name</b></td></tr>
    </table>
```

Or, alternatively, you can use a linked CSS style sheet like this:

```
#abc1 {
    border: 1px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

Just to let you know, setting the height of the table element sets the height of each row, if you want to set the height of the whole table, put the table in div tags and set the height of that element. 

 
 What are you missing? you're missing the concept of styling with CSS, try this tutorial: [HTMLdog.com](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/)

Answer (score 3):

I just solved a similar problem.

For this I used the line-height property for setting each element of table's size.

Also, here you can find more information: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Here is it's usage:

```html
<table style='line-height: 3px'>
```

Also you can use percentages instead of absolute values.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to know which html renderer will render your html code. Visit this site: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ , after this you can decide which solution is better.

1) Use inline-css for your table tag like this:

```
<table style="height:50px;"></table>`
```

2) Use an internal style sheet for your table tags like this:

```
<head>
  <style>
    table { height:50px; }
    p { color:blue; }
  </style>
</head>
```

3) Use an external style sheet like this and give a height value for the table like this:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Or you can give a value for the td elements and then the table will automatically figure out it's size.

Example: if you work on an html email you can't use external css. You need to solve it with inline-css (solution 1 above). If it's not supported you are still able to do it in the td tags.

Answer (score -2):

The following code works:

```
table{
  height: 86px; 
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: You are changing the behaviour of table itself.