# How to set Height of a table in a Bootstrap as the value of Width using CSS?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I'm having a Table, designed using Bootstrap CSS. I need to set the height as same as the value of width of the Table. In Bootstrap, the width can be changed according to the device. Kindly assist

> Note: Kindly give solution using CSS. Don't use the Javascript or
>   any other raw value feeding.

```
+---------+
|   CSS   |
|  Table  |
|   1:1   |
+---------+
```

My HTML Source Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Bootstrap Table</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
  <table class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="height:calc(width);" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Table height in html is determined by the number of rows.  In most cases, setting a height value on the table will be meaningless. See the first answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351545/not-able-to-set-table-height).

Comment: In my case, the table is 4 X 4. The number of Rows is fixed. I need the aspect resolution of the Table as 1 : 1

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan, you need to make table cell square to make whole table square

Comment: @bravokeyl - exactly same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The essential issue here, as mentioned in the comments, is getting the individual cells to remain square.  Doing this in css is rather trivial, as demonstrated by a number of answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout).  The real problem is dealing with content that may not be uniformly sized.

This is one way of doing it, although admittedly it's a bit hacky: Add a `div` to at least one cell in each row, that has `padding-bottom: 100%`, and `position:relative`.  Then add another `div` with `position:absolute` to each cell.  This last `div` will be where you put your content.  Then I had to remove the cell padding added by bootstrap (alternatively you could just set cell width to 25% and skip the bootstrap class, which is probably not giving you any advantage in the table itself).  You'll have to play with `overflow` attribs on the divs to control how the content gets displayed under various circumstances.

I also wrote you a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6tL0v0b/3/) that looks like it solves your issue.

Note: this model makes the assumption that there will always be 4 and only 4 rows in the table (hence the `padding-bottom: 25%`).

Comment: You should also make sure you understand how the bootstrap column classes work - you were setting the same classes on the table and it's `div` wrapper, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I think the explanations I added flesh it out a bit, and the -1 is undeserved.

Comment: While the explanations might flesh it out, they don't counter the basic problem which is that people have to visit a third party site to understand the answer. The bones of the answer need to be in the answer, not just the flesh.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10694038)

Comment: Thanks @jegesh. your fiddle link gives me the solution for my requirement. Thanks alot.

Comment: @FabioLuz I changed the answer to be more "up to code". Pun intended.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan Please mark the answer as correct, kind friend.

Comment: @jegesh - The Table is not scaled as the aspect ration 1:1

Comment: @good work... I marked your answer as answer for the post. If I put any text to the cell. Then immediately it collapsed the aspect ration.

Comment: I changed things so the content won't break it, but you may to fiddle further with the overflow attributes.

Comment: @jegesh - Kindly check the text alignment. The Text are placed below the Cell.