# Unable to change table height

Tags: html

I have a table and i want to change its height but when i add the hieght element in the css, nothing changes, i also tried a solution on stackoverflow ([Not able to set table height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351545/not-able-to-set-table-height)) but none seem to be working. What am i doing wrong?

HTML -

```
 <div class="tableDiv">
       <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" id="StoreData">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>County / Admin district</th>
                <th>Postcode</th>
                <th>Longitude</th>
                <th>Latitude</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           {% for Postcode, LongLat in LocationData.items() %}
           <tr>
             <td>{{ LongLat[0] }}</td>
             <td>{{ Postcode }}</td>
             <td>{{ LongLat[1] }}</td>
             <td>{{ LongLat[2] }}</td>
           </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </table>
      </div>
```

CSS -

```
   <style media="screen">
      html, body, table {
      height: 100%;
      }
      .tableDiv {
      height: 50%;
      }
      table thead {
      position: sticky;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 999;
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      }
      #storeform {
      margin-left: 700px;
      margin-top: 50px;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      }
      #StoreData {
      margin: 10px auto;
      padding: 10;
      width: 1250px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      }
   </style>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding html,body{ height:100%}

Comment: @adel Thanks for the comment, that didnt seem to work

Comment: Is the div u want to change height or table?

Comment: @adel The table height, the solution that i looked up and linked in the question told me to wrap the table up in a div and add the height to that.

Comment: But u need to add height to ur table:  add html,body,table{height:100%} now table will take full height of the div wich is 50%

Comment: @adel didnt work :/, i will update my css so you can see

Comment: Here is the codepen : https://codepen.io/iziz96/pen/XwxKZJ   i dont know why its not working with !

Comment: @adel I see it is working in codepen, i will find a way to fix tihs problem, thank you for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Fixed Layout

Tables by nature conform to their content. Whatever is within a `<td>` influences the `<td>s` width and height and in turn affects the `<tr>` and then the `<tbody>`, and finally the `<table>`. This default behavior is set by `table-layout:auto` which is only applicable to either `<table>` or a container element with `display: table` or `display: inline-table`. The only other value for `table-layout` is `fixed`. A *"fixed"* table gives the developer more control over the table's behavior by honoring any specified widths given to any `<th>` (if there are no `<th>` then the `<td>` in the top `tr>`). Since BootStrap is used, we can assign `.table-fixed` class to `<table>` the equivalent to `table {`table-layout: fixed}`.

Now to control the content within a `<td>` place a `<div>` or any similar block-level element in each `<td>`. If you wish to have a `min-width` or `width` of any row just apply it to just one of the `<div>`. Note there are extra rows added and each actually has content: `#&nbsp;` or non-breaking space which prevents an empty cell from collapsing -- an alternative is to assign each `<div>` a `min-height`.

The `<div>` containing the table has the BS class `.table-responsive` and is at 50% of the `<body>` height (also at 100% by BS default). This layout facilitates control on the table externally.

Now we have control of the table width and indirectly the table height. When content is added, and the column width is set explicitly, the content will wrap to the next line instead of stretching the cell. In turn as the cell gains each line so does the row, etc.

Not everything is 100% due to the many unknown factors your real layout may or may not have so when commenting please do not say *"It doesn't work"*. First establish any details that we have missed and then what you observe what's not working and how it should work/appear.

#### Demo

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.table-responsive {
  height: 50%;
}

table {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-fixed" id="StoreData">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-4">County / District</th>
        <th class="col-xs-2">Zip Code</th>
        <th class="col-xs-3">Longitude</th>
        <th class="col-xs-3">Latitude</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>Bermuda Triangle</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>33036</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>25.0000</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>-71.0000</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```